# How would I edit 4 images into one?

Tags: png, sprite, batch-processing

I have a ton of sprites in folders, however, they're all decompiled. I want to compile them all into their respective sprite sheets. For instance, this is the folder layout.

```
back
     guy.png
     girl.png
front
     guy.png
     girl.png
left
     guy.png
     girl.png
right
     guy.png
     girl.png
```

How do I merge these into a single guy.png or girl.png? (however instead of just 2 separate entities I have 400+).

Whether it's through programming or a batch image processor, a little guide on doing this would be really helpful!

Comment: Why merge them with C++? If I understand correctly you want merged images, but it should not matter with what tool they are merged. There are image editors that support batch image processing. Maybe GIMP script in batch mode can be used.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware. I'm probably most experienced with C++ so it'd just be easier for me. I'll look into it!

Comment: Rephrased the question, thank you!

Comment: This question is more about choosing a language and a imaging library, which could and should be googled before asked.

Comment: I have done that, however I haven't found something that does what I want to do so far.